# Cluster work node not ready after server reboot

Tags: kubernetes

The work node change Ready to NotReady when I reboot master and work node.

The result of `kubectl get nodes`.

```
NAME                      STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
XXX                       NotReady   work     13d   v1.17.2
XXX                       Ready      master   13d   v1.17.2
```

The result of `kubectl get pod --all-namespaces`.

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default         postgres                                          1/1     Running   0          20m
default         user-api                                          3/3     Running   0          20m
ingress-nginx   nginx-ingress-controller                          1/1     Running   3          10d
kube-system     coredns                                           1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     coredns                                           1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     etcd                                              1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     kube-apiserver                                    1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     kube-controller-manager                           1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-amd64                             1/1     Running   3          13d
kube-system     kube-flannel-ds-amd64                             1/1     Running   5          13d
kube-system     kube-proxy                                        1/1     Running   4          13d
kube-system     kube-proxy                                        1/1     Running   3          13d
kube-system     kube-scheduler                                    1/1     Running   4          13d
```

How should I check this problem out?

Comment: kubectl logs of nodes when the nodes are not ready

Comment: Is the command `kubectl logs node <node_id>`?

Comment: sorry I meant kubelet logs

Comment: It has too many message and I can not find any useful error output.

Comment: can you get output of kubectl describe node nodename ? can you grep for registration in kubelet logs? Also grep for any error in kubelet logs.

Comment: Please, can you share the output for `kubectl describe node MASTER_NODE_NAME`?

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting `kubelet` of the node which is in `notReady` state and it may solve your problem.

The below command can help:

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```